# why 13 and 10 are read instead of 10 for change of line

Tags: java

The ascii value for change of line is 10, but when I am reading a text file two ascii values are read 13 & 10 instead of 10 for change of line, please tell why this is happening and what does ascii value 13 means here???

Comment: It means you're on Windows.

Comment: depending on systems, new line can be encoded as `'\r\n'`, `'\n'`, or `'\r'` en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: Simple google search also turns up that ASCII(13) is the carriage return, `\r`.

Comment: If you'll post the code that you're using to read the text-file, you can get a better answer, that will show you how you *should* be reading it. (Because you should not need to worry about getting ASCII 13: the JDK is perfectly capable of abstracting that away for you.)

Answer (score 5):

In [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) the line terminator is `\r\n`, not just `\n`.

Comment: That's true, but does it really answer the OP's question? Normally, when you read a text-file on Windows, you don't see the `\r`. You only see if it you're reading a text-file in binary mode.

Answer (score 2):

New lines are encoded differently, for example as '\r\n', '\n', or '\r'

[wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Answer (score 0):

13 is cr -Carriage return; Apple Mac (Classic) line terminator; 1st part of Windows line terminator

10 is nl Newline; Unix line terminator; 2nd part of Windows line terminator

[Refer ASCII Codes](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/ascii.html)